# React native error install failed already exists

Tags: react-native

I just started working with react native. I created a new project using

```
react-native init ChatSample.
```

Then i run this command

```
react-native run-android --deviceId MYDEVICEID
```

Now after finishing 100% it shows this error

> adb: failed to install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install com.chatsample without first uninstalling.]

I moved to this folder and found that app-debug.apk exists there so i deleted it, but again when i run this command it shows same error.

Then i deleted the complete build folder and run this command but still got the same error. More precisely when it is around 50% it starts creating build folder and app-debug.apk and as soon as it reaches 100% app-debug.apk file is created in that folder. But why is the error coming, like this is a fresh project and all i did is just run two command first for creating project and other for running app.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the project in Android Studio from the `ProjectFile/android`. Then build and run on your Phone

Comment: :-) Then what is the use of this command *"react-native run-android --deviceId ###"* nonetheless, i will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

Is in your device the APK installed? Try uninstalling the APK from the device and then run the command again.

Comment: Totally absurd, please read question carefully i only ran 2 commands, how is the app going to be installed on mobile when i am running the command for the first time and it is giving me error